# Target in Echoed php link

Tags: php, html, target

I have a problem I can't solve by myself, don't know how simple it is to solve but I want to open this link in another frame:

```
<?php echo "<a href=details.php?id=$row[idProdukt]>$row[Produkt_Namn]</a>" ?>
```

tried to use taget but since it's html I couldn't really wrap my head around how to type it.
any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the attribute to your anchor tag as usual. Make sure you use the name of the targeted iframe as its value:

```
<?php echo "<a href='details.php?id=$row[idProdukt]' target='framename'>$row[Produkt_Namn]</a>" ?>
```

I added quotes around your html attribute values as that is a good practice to be in. It prevents issues arising from errant or intentional spaces in attribute values.

Comment: We've all overlooked something simple at one point or another

Comment: *+1*: It's a good idea to use `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting the variables for preventing XSS (and similar) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have error on array index, missing quotes. You can use this;

```
<iframe src="some_url" name="test">
.....
</iframe>


<?php echo "<a href=\"details.php?id=" . $row['idProdukt'] . "\" target=\"test\">" . $row['Produkt_Namn'] . "</a>"; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The trouble is missing quotes around `href` attribute value and array key.

```
echo "<a href=\"details.php?id={$row['idProdukt']}\">{$row['Produkt_Namn']}</a>";
```

[See in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yVSHYR)